# Assigning multiple routes for a single item in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a book item and I want to assign two routes for it. Is it possible with react? For example, when I click the item from the homepage route should be 'books/:id'. If I checked the book from a specific category page the route should be 'books/categoryName/:id'. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using in order to set the routes? What you want to achieve is totally possible in react, but it's hard to explain without some code as reference

Comment: Can't you create another Route object with the same component and a different path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Route's path property accept either `string` or `string[]`. See the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string)